# Why is my app interface not visible in iOS5.1 with XCode 4.5 unless multitasking>

Tags: ios, ios5

I have an app that I am upgrading to work better in iOS6. Previously it worked all fine in iOS5 but for some reason with the new XCode ang iOS5.1 simulator and on device all I see is a white screen. I can tap the screen and get the debug info that shows the interface is in there somewhere, I just can't see it.

For info I have a custom UINavigationController with a rootViewController. That UINavigationController is set as the window rootviewcontroller and it all works perfectly in iOS6.

The weirdest thing is that as soon as I open the multitasking tray or do a five finger swipe to switch apps the interface appears. All my applicationWillResignActive etc methods in my app delegate are empty so wtf is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: The view is definately there because I can tap where I know buttons are and the console output is correct. Also, why would pausing the application make it appear?

Comment: maybe some missing event (viewWillAppear) or something like that. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it at LAST thanks to: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1719

The problem came from the window object in the MainWindow.xib file that had been there since iOS3! Just deleted it and the app worked a treat. I guess the reason the interface could get gestures etc but nothing was visible was the additional UIWindow object in front of it all.

You live and learn I guess!

Martin